# Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last) https://github.com/HxnDev/Graphical-Password-Authentication-System (link for all code)

Tags: python, passwords

I am working on a graphic password authentication system and have been getting this error while running my main class.

```py
# Import the required libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import custom_button
import garbled
import obscure
import password
import segments


def load_garbled(window, menu_frame):
    menu_frame.pack_forget()
    garbled.start(window)


def load_obscured(window, menu_frame):
    menu_frame.pack_forget()
    obscure.start(window)


def load_segmented(window, menu_frame):
    menu_frame.pack_forget()
    segments.start(window)


def load_password(window, menu_frame):
    menu_frame.pack_forget()
    password.start(window)


def start(win):
    win.geometry("1280x600")
    win.title("Graphical Authentication System")

    menu_frame = Frame(win, height=600, width=1280)
    menu_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    label = Label(menu_frame, text="Graphical Authentication System", font=('Freestyle Script', 54))
    label.pack(padx=40, pady=30)

    btn_height = 90
    btn_width = 450
    btn_font = ('Trebuchet MS', 14)

    btn1 = custom_button.TkinterCustomButton(master=menu_frame, text="Test Garbled Images", text_font=btn_font,
                                             height=btn_height, width=btn_width, corner_radius=10,
                                             command=lambda: load_garbled(win, menu_frame)).place(relx=0.3, rely=0.4,
                                                                                                  anchor=CENTER)
    btn2 = custom_button.TkinterCustomButton(master=menu_frame, text="Test Segmented Images", text_font=btn_font,
                                             height=btn_height, width=btn_width, corner_radius=10,
                                             command=lambda: load_segmented(win, menu_frame)).place(relx=0.3,
                                                                                                    rely=0.7,
                                                                                                    anchor=CENTER)
    btn3 = custom_button.TkinterCustomButton(master=menu_frame, text="Test Obscured Images", text_font=btn_font,
                                             height=btn_height, width=btn_width, corner_radius=10,
                                             command=lambda: load_obscured(win, menu_frame)).place(relx=0.7,
                                                                                                   rely=0.4,
                                                                                                   anchor=CENTER)
    btn4 = custom_button.TkinterCustomButton(master=menu_frame, text="Test Password/Image Authentication",
                                             text_font=btn_font,
                                             height=btn_height, width=btn_width, corner_radius=10,
                                             command=lambda: load_password(win, menu_frame)).place(relx=0.7,
                                                                                                   rely=0.7,
                                                                                                   anchor=CENTER)

    win.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Tk()
    start(win)
```

[image: enter link description here]

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jalaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\jalaj\Downloads\Python Course with Notes\2. Chapter 2\.vscode\python\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\custom_button.py", line 274, in clicked
    self.function()
  File "c:\Users\jalaj\Downloads\Python Course with Notes\2. Chapter 2\.vscode\python\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\main_menu.py", line 47, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: load_garbled(win, menu_frame)).place(relx=0.3, rely=0.4,
  File "c:\Users\jalaj\Downloads\Python Course with Notes\2. Chapter 2\.vscode\python\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\main_menu.py", line 13, in load_garbled
    garbled.start(window)
  File "c:\Users\jalaj\Downloads\Python Course with Notes\2. Chapter 2\.vscode\python\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\garbled.py", line 19, in start
    garbledImages = utils.getGarbledImages()
  File "c:\Users\jalaj\Downloads\Python Course with Notes\2. Chapter 2\.vscode\python\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\Graphical-Password-Authentication-System-main\utils.py", line 23, in getGarbledImages
    imagePaths = os.listdir("garbledImages")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'garbledImages'
```

Comment: The problem is in `imagePaths = os.listdir("garbledImages")` as the error is telling you. There isn't a folder named `garbledImages` in the current working directory. Therefore, this question doesn't need the `tkinter` tag or even the `passwords` tag

Comment: code may run in different folder than you expect (in different `Current Working Directory`) and you can check it using `print( os.getcwd() )`. You may need to use `"C:\full\path\to\garbledImages"`. OR you may need to get folder with code `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and use `os.listdir( os.path.join(BASE, "garbledImages") )`